# Filter by Label of HTML elements in lightning client side controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have anchor tags inside `<li>` and trying to filter them based on user input in text box.

My `<li>` tags have:
Apple
Pineapple
Appexchange
Salesforce

If someone types app in the text box, the list should display
Apple
Pineapple
Appexchange

May I know how I can do this with lightning client controller?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I did such functionality in my old VF page, where I used jQuery text() on anchor tag and search() with regex. Then I'd add/remove class on the element and set display property based on class.

if(j$(this).find("a").text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
j$(this).removeClass("testing");
} else {
j$(this).addClass("testing");
}

j$(".accordion-content").each(function(){
if ( j$( this ).find("div").hasClass( "testing" ) ) {
j$(this).css({ 'display': "block" });}else{
j$(this).css({ 'display': "none" });
}});

Comment: I am learning Lightning and this is my first attempt to migrate the old VF page to Lightning. Learned that search() is not recommended. Any pointers here?

Comment: were you able to try the below?

Comment: @glls with little modification, I was able to do this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can achieve the fucntionality with the following elements:

- Your Input Element
- A collection type attribute
- Method that receives the value
- Method that searches and updates the displayable elements (I split my method, controller and helper)

In the following example, I have a lightning:input component that uses an onchange event handler, as well as a value attribute:

```
<lightning:input aura:id="query-box" type="search" name="search" placeholder="additional filtering" onchange="{!c.queryElements}" value="{!v.searchInut}"/>
```

In my controller, I have a method that gets the value in my input elements everytime it changes:

```
queryElements  : function(cmp, event, helper) {

    const typedQuery = event.getSource().get('v.value');            
    const suggArray = cmp.get('v.querySuggestions');
    try{
        helper.updateList(cmp, event, typedQuery); 
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e.message);
    }
},
```

and finally, in your helper, add the logic for updating whatever collection  type you decide to use:

```
updateList : function(cmp, event, inp){
    let activeSuggestionArray = [];
    /*
        Logic for evaluating what the input should return
    */
    //Finally, update your collection tpye attribute
cmp.set('v.activeList', activeSuggestionArray);

}
```

Example component.cmp:

```
<aura:attribute name="activeList" type="List" default="[]"/>

<lightning:input aura:id="query-box" type="search" name="search" placeholder="additional filtering" onchange="{!c.queryElements}" value="{!v.searchInut}"/>

        <ul aura:id="dynamic-ul" >
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.activeList}" var="dynLi">
                <li aura:id="dynamic-item" >{!dynLi}</li>
            </aura:iteration>
        </ul>
```

when you update your collection type, the aura:iteration will re-evaluate and re-render the displayable elements.